# Passing Data with Intents crashes app android

Tags: android, android-intent, crash

Why is my app crashing when I try to pass some data with intents?

```
 case 0:
             Intent intent=new Intent(context, RMpro.class);
             intent.putExtra("NAME", "Projectile!");
             intent.putExtra("PATH", R.raw.s14projectil);
             intent.putExtra("FILE", "Projectile.mp3");
             ((Activity)context).startActivity(intent);

             break;
```

In RMpro Activity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ringtone);

  Intent i=this.getIntent();

       final  String C1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("PATH").trim();
       final  String A1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME").trim();
       final  String B1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("FILE").trim();
```

Why is this happening?
My Logcat:

```
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mostpopularalarmringtones/com.mostpopularalarmringtones.RMpro}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     at com.mostpopularalarmringtones.RMpro.onCreate(RMpro.java:37)
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-08 16:07:34.811: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     ... 11 more
```

What I did wrong in here? Why is my application crashing?

Comment: which line is the 37th line in `RMpro` class?

Comment: I think ` R.raw.s14projectil` as you pass it via `PATH` is a integer not a String

Comment: Line 37 is ` final  String C1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("PATH").trim();` So what should I do about that? How do I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always check if result of `getIntent()` is `null` or not:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
if (i != null){
    final  String C1 = i.getStringExtra("PATH").trim();
    final  String A1 = i.getStringExtra("NAME").trim();
    final  String B1 = i.getStringExtra("FILE").trim();
    ....
}
```

Moreover, when you put data to your `Intent` and later retrieve it with `getStringExtra`, you should make sure, that you put `String`. The value of `R.raw.s14projectil` is always `int`. If `s14projectil` is the file with data, you should read it at first by opening `InputStream`:

```
InputStream raw = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.s14projectil);
```

And only after that pass the content to intent.

Comment: `intent.putExtra("PATH", String.valueOf(R.raw.s14projectil));`

This fixed it. Now it's working as it should. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

You put `int` into extras (`R.raw.s14projectil` is value of `int`):

`intent.putExtra("PATH", R.raw.s14projectil);`

And then try to retrieve a string:

`final  String C1 = i.getStringExtra("PATH").trim();`

That is why you get `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it may help you.

```
Case 0:
Intent intent=new Intent(context, RMpro.class);
Bundle extra = new Bundle();
extra.putString("NAME", "Projectile!");
extra.putString("PATH", R.raw.s14projectil);
extra.putString("FILE", "Projectile.mp3");
intent.putExtras(extra);
((Activity)context).startActivity(intent);
```

And in RMpro Activity:

```
Intent Rmintent= getIntent();
Bundle extras = Rmintent.getExtras();
final  String C1 = extras.getString("PATH").trim();
final  String A1 = extras.getString("NAME").trim();
final  String B1 = extras.getString("FILE").trim();
```